# Contract is failing on approve function in Ethereum with Solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

My contract file is this http://prntscr.com/pvvkme.
My Test file are these http://prntscr.com/pvvkme & http://prntscr.com/pvvlmg
My migration file is this http://prntscr.com/pvvm5b
My errors are these http://prntscr.com/pvvmqg & http://prntscr.com/pvvmxr

Comment: Please post ALL the relevant information and ONLY the relevant information in PLAINTEXT (not links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approval is likely working, but you're checking for a `Transfer` event after you call `approve`. Change that section to check for an `Approval` event and it should work.